# Mandatory empty line after function definition SwiftLint

Tags: swift, swiftlint

I am integrating swiftlint in my xcode project and setting it's configuration. But I am not able to get the rule which enforces an empty line after function definition

```
func test1() {
}
func test2() {
}
```

If I add multiple spaces between two functions there is a rule for that.

Is there any rule which can be used to enable empty line between two functions or I need to write custom one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing swiftlint rules will give you a list of rules that are available. What I usually do to find the rule applicable is change different rules in the yaml file until i find the one that does what I want.

If your rule does not exist, I suggest writing a custom rule using regex such as:

```
 custom_rules:
  pirates_beat_ninjas: # rule identifier
    included: ".*\\.swift" # regex that defines paths to include during linting. optional.
    excluded: ".*Test\\.swift" # regex that defines paths to exclude during linting. optional
    name: "Pirates Beat Ninjas" # rule name. optional.
    regex: "([nN]inja)" # matching pattern
    capture_group: 0 # number of regex capture group to highlight the rule violation at. optional.
    match_kinds: # SyntaxKinds to match. optional.
      - comment
      - identifier
    message: "Pirates are better than ninjas." # violation message. optional.
    severity: error # violation severity. optional.
  no_hiding_in_strings:
    regex: "([nN]inja)"
    match_kinds: string
```

This rule makes it so that every time you see the word Ninja, it causes a violation